# List index out of range, a movie recommender system in python

Tags: python, arrays

I was doing feature preprocessing for Movie recommendation system. I got the following error message after running this code in jupyter notebook.

```py
from tmdbv3api import Movie
tmdb_movie = Movie()
def get_genre(x):
    genres = []
    result = tmdb_movie.search(x)
    movie_id = result[0].id
    response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key={}'.format(movie_id,tmdb.api_key))
    data_json = response.json()
    if data_json['genres']:
        genre_str = " " 
        for i in range(0,len(data_json['genres'])):
            genres.append(data_json['genres'][i]['name'])
        return genre_str.join(genres)
    else:
        np.NaN

df_2020['genres'] = df_2020['Title'].map(lambda x: get_genre(str(x)))
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-14-fdc91464740e> in <module>
    ----> 1 df_2020['genres'] = df_2020['Title'].map(lambda x: get_genre(str(x)))


IndexError: list index out of range
```

#shape

```
df_2020 has shape of 232 by 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no return statement in the else block.